# Capacitor VoiceRecorder in Ionic to WhisperAPI File Format Incompatibility

Tags: ionic-framework, openai-api, chatgpt-api, openai-whisper

I have a app in IONIC for android and IOS. There'll be a button to record speech and on stop it will send it to WhisperAPI for transcription. The API doesnt work on Android and IOS due to audio format issue which is unsupported by WhisperAPI. Right now Android records in aac format. How to convert to wav to upload to WhisperAPI. I've tried a few method but doesn't work.

````
    if (this.recording === false) {
      try {
        const result = await VoiceRecorder.startRecording();
        alert(result.value);
        this.recording = true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error starting recording:', error);
      }
    } else {
      try {
        const result = await VoiceRecorder.stopRecording();
        
        const audioData = new Uint8Array(atob(result.value.recordDataBase64).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));

        const audioBlob = new Blob([audioData], { type: result.value.mimeType });
        // Create a FormData object and append the audioBlob to it
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', audioBlob, 'audio.wav');
        formData.append('model', 'whisper-1');

        const contents =  await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: 'test.wav',
          data: result.value.recordDataBase64,
          directory: Directory.External,
        });
        

        const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.apiKey}`,
          },
        });
       
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        this.userInput = data.text;
        this.userInput = this.userInput.trim();
        this.sendUserInput();
        this.recording = false;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error stopping recording:', error);
      }
    }
  } ```
````